# Moving hadoop folder into /usr/local/hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to move the Hadoop installation to the `/usr/local/hadoop` directory, but it says-

```
mv: cannot move ‘/home/pg/Desktop/hadoop-2.7.1’ to ‘/user/local/hadoop’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/hadoop` ≠ `/user/local/hadoop`.

Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: As you're (nearly) a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!